# FaunaDB: how to fetch a custom column

Tags: faunadb

I'm just learning FaunaDB and FQL and having some trouble (mainly because I come from MySQL). I can successfully query a table (eg: `users`) and fetch a specific user. This user has a property `users.expiry_date` which is a faunadb `Time()` type.

What I would like to do is know if this date has expired by using the function `LT(Now(), users.expiry_date)`, but I don't know how to create this query. Do I have to create an `Index` first?

So in short, just fetching one of the `users` documents gets me this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  username: 'test',
  expiry_date: Time("2022-01-10T16:01:47.394Z")
}
```

But I would like to get this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  username: 'test',
  expiry_date: Time("2022-01-10T16:01:47.394Z"),
  has_expired: true,
}
```

I have this FQL query now (ignore `oauthInfo`):

```
Query(
  Let(
    {
     oauthInfo: Select(['data'], Get(Ref(Collection('user_oauth_info'), refId))),
     user: Select(['data'], Get(Select(['user_id'], Var('oauthInfo'))))
    },
    Merge({ oauthInfo: Var('oauthInfo') }, { user: Var('user') })
  )
)
```

How would I do the equivalent of the mySQL query `SELECT users.*, IF(users.expiry_date < NOW(), 1, 0) as is_expired FROM users` in FQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `Let` and `Merge` show that you are thinking about FQL in a good way.  These are functions that can go a long way to making your queries more organized and readable!

I will start with some notes, but they will be relevant to the final answer, so please stick with me.

### The `Query` function

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/query

First, you should not need to wrap anything in the `Query` function, here.  `Query` is necessary for defining functions in FQL that will be run later, for example, in the User-Defined Function `body`.  You will always see it as `Query(Lambda(...))`.

### Fauna IDs

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/learn/understanding/documents

Remember that Fauna assigns unique IDs for every Document for you.  When I see fields named `id`, that is a bit of a red flag, so I want to highlight that.  There are plenty of reasons that you might store some business-ID in a Document, but be sure that you need it.

#### Getting an ID

A Document in Fauna is shaped like:

```js
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("users"), "101"), // <-- "id" is 101
  ts: 1641508095450000,
  data: { /* ... */ }
}
```

In the JS driver you can use this id by using `documentResult.ref.id` (other drivers can do this in similar ways)

You can access the ID directly in FQL as well.  You use the `Select` function.

```js
Let(
  {
   user: Get(Select(['user_id'], Var('oauthInfo')))
   id: Select(["ref", "id"], Var("user"))
  },
  Var("id")
)
```

### More about the `Select` function.

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/select

You are already using `Select` and that's the function you are looking for.  It's what you use to grab any piece of an object or array.

Here's a contrived example that gets the zip code for the 3rd user in the Collection:

```js
Let(
  {
   page: Paginate(Documents(Collection("user")),
  },
  Select(["data", 2, "data", "address", "zip"], Var("user"))
)
```

### Bring it together

That said, your `Let` function is a great start.  Let's break things down into smaller steps.

```js
Let(
  {
   oauthInfo_ref: Ref(Collection('user_oauth_info'), refId)
   oauthInfo_doc: Get(Var("oathInfoRef")),
 
   // make sure that user_oath_info.user_id is a full Ref, not just a number
   user_ref: Select(["data", "user_id"], Var("oauthInfo_doc"))
   user_doc: Get(Var("user_ref")),
   user_id: Select("id", Var("user_ref")),

   // calculate expired
   expiry_date: Select(["data", "expiry_date"], Var("user_doc")),
   has_expired: LT(Now(), Var("expiry_date"))
  },

  // if the data does not overlap, Merge is not required.
  // you can build plain objects in FQL
  { 
    oauthInfo: Var("oauthInfo_doc"), // entire Document
    user: Var("user_doc"),           // entire Document
    has_expired: Var("has_expired")  // an extra field
  }
)
```

Instead of returning the auth info and user as separate points if you do want to Merge them and/or add additional fields, then feel free to do that

```js
  // ...
  Merge(
    Select("data", Var("user_doc")),  // just the data
    {
      user_id: Var("user_id"),        // added field
      has_expired: Var("has_expired") // added field
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: First of all, sorry, the first two points are because of my poor creation of examples. I'm not actually using the `Query` function, it's actually the (javascript) `client.query` function. Also the `users` table does not really have an integer value `id`, with that I actually meant the `id` generated by fauna.

Comment: Thank you, with a few tweaks this totally works! Very cool to see the power of the `Let` function in practice.